# Create a shortlist/collection of items on a website with Facebook Like API

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have a client site where we currently have a much underused 'shortlist' feature for items listed on the website. In this case the items are properties for sale, users can add the ones they are interested in to a shortlist for future reference.

We also recently added Facebook 'Like' buttons to the website which have had a lot of use, the barrier of entry is lower (I guess) because users are already logged in to Facebook.

What I would therefore like to do is modify the property shortlist feature so that it simply displays a list of the properties that a logged in Facebook user has 'Liked' on the clients domain.

How would I get at this data (either via PHP or JS) using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's not possible out of the box. You have two possibilities:

1. Display a social plugin ([Activity Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/)) to display the recent actions (e.g. "like") on the mentioned. The plugin itself is like a drop in widget, so you can't style it at all.
2. Ask the user for the "[user_likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/user-friend-permissions/)" permission. If the user authenticates your app and the additional permission, you can perform a fql query to get all liked items. It's a little more complicated then (1), but with the mentioned permission you have all required data to perform the custom sort algorithm you want.

Comment: Thanks Johannes - I think option 2 sounds like the best solution ultimately. I'll have to do some reading up on the log-in plug-in. :)